# Parametrization of a boundary of a closed disk

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametrization

The  question that I am referring to is:

Let $D$ be the closed disc bounded by the circle with equation

$$(x-6)^{2} + y^{2} = 36$$

I am asked to find the parameterization of the boundary.

I am a bit confused on how to do this. I know that $x^2 + y^2 = 36$ which means $r = 6$.

Since $x = r\cos(\theta)$ and $y = r\sin(\theta)$, how would the $(x-6)^2$ be parameterized?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

In general, if we are given the circumference
\begin{align*}
(x-a)^{2} + (y-b)^{2} = r^{2}
\end{align*}

we can parametrize it as follows

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x = a + r\cos(\theta)\\\\
y = b + r\sin(\theta)
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

where $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$. Can you apply it to the example proposed?